# O que significa colocar um tipo antes de uma declaração?

Tags: java, http, http-request

Olá, estava estudando HTTP Requests em Java quando me deparei com um código e em certa linha ocorria uma declaração um tanto quanto estranha para mim, alguém pode me explicar o que significa um tipo antes de uma declaração?

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = null;
 URL url = new URL(targetURL);
 connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Esta declaração
```

Desculpem a ignorancia no assunto, mas alguém pode me explicar o porque do tipo HttpURLConnection antes do resto da designação? Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Isso é chamado de cast, é usado para converter um tipo de valor para outro tipo, nesse caso ele esta convertendo o tipo URL em HttpURLConnection

Comment: Obrigado amigo, não gosto muito de copiar e colar sem entender o código! Você me ajudou demais! Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A expressao **url.openConnection();** retorna um URLConnection. Analisando a API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) podemos verificar que HttpURLConnection é uma sub-classe da URLConnection. Por este motivo é possível fazer cast, portanto alterar a declaração de um tipo para outro sub-tipo, com a expressão:

> (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();